# Firefox selenium driver fails in headless mode where chrome works due to timeout exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, headless

I'm having troubles to debug why is firefox not working in headless mode. This is how I create the drivers:

```py
def __get_firefox_options(headless=True) -> webdriver.FirefoxOptions:
    """
    Get Firefox configuration
    """
    options=webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    if headless == True:
        options.headless = True
        options.add_argument("window-size=1920x1080")
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

    return options

def __get_firefox_driver(drivers_path, headless) -> webdriver.Firefox:
    """
    Return an instance of the geckodriver
    """
    driver_path = os.path.join(drivers_path, 'geckodriver.exe')

    service = FirefoxService(driver_path)

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(
        service=service,
        options=__get_firefox_options(headless=headless)
    )
    driver.maximize_window()
    return driver
```

And chrome:

```py
def __get_chrome_options(headless=False) -> webdriver.ChromeOptions:
    """
    Get chrome setup to allow self signed certificates
    """
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    if headless == True:
        options.headless = True
        options.add_argument("window-size=1920x1080")
    options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"]) # Disable logging

    return options

def __get_chrome_driver(drivers_path, headless) -> webdriver.Chrome:
    """
    Return an instance of the chromedriver
    """
    driver_path = os.path.join(drivers_path, 'chromedriver.exe')

    service = ChromeService(driver_path)

    return webdriver.Chrome(
        service=service,
        options=__get_chrome_options(headless)
    )
```

Now I want to find a login element:

```py
from loguru import logger
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

def access_login_page(driver: webdriver.Chrome or webdriver.Firefox) -> None:
    """
    Access the login page using the header menu
    """
    ELEMENT_ID = 'header-sign-in'
    try:
        element: WebElement = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, ELEMENT_ID))
        )
        element.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        logger.error(f'Element "{ELEMENT_ID}" could not be found')
```

So this small piece of code works in chrome, chrome headless and firefox, but not in firefox headless.

Before I was having an element not interactable exception, therefore I changed it to `element_to_be_clickable`, but not it justs is stucked there and ends up with the `TimeoutException`.

I am not able to  debug it because in the non headless mode it works, how can I try to fix this? What can be different in the configuration of firefox when the headless proeperty is used?
If it helps to get an idea, this is how the DOM looks like:

[image: DOM]

Answer (score 0):

After minimizing the code to write this question I found the issue. The page has a responsive mode where the button I am using gets hidden at a certian screen size.

It seems taht in headless mode firefox takes a different resolution for `driver.maximize_window()` than running it in my full hd monitor not headless. Thereofre my monitor would return:

```json
{'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}
```

while in headless mode:

```
{'width': 1366, 'height': 768}
```

Therefore I changed the following in the driver creation function:

```py
    if headless:
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
    else:
        driver.maximize_window()
```

On the other hand I had to add this option `driver.maximize_window()` because the options `options.add_argument("window-size=1920x1080")` where not working out of the box for my firefox `96.0.3 (64-bit)`.